# Default menus not visible in backend , also frontend not loading properly

Tags: magento-1.9, admin

I disabled some modules in backend in `System > configuration > Advanced > Advanced`

Then I logged out and login and then some default magento menus are not visible.

[image]

Please have a look at core_config_data table view after searching for all modules for their enabled status:

[image]

Comment: Which modules did you disable?

Comment: @MohitKumarArora i remember i disabled only custom modules, not sure about it.

Comment: If you have access to database, then you can check which modules you have disabled by searching like **%advanced/modules_disable_output/%** in **core_config_data** table, and then enable if any module has been disabled accidentally.

Comment: @MohitKumarArora can you please give me complete sql query to check it , so that i can run the query and check it.

Comment: SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE `path` LIKE '%advanced/modules_disable_output/%' ORDER BY `path` ASC

Comment: @MohitKumarArora please check updated question, i posted an image, seems i disabled some default modules also. now i can enable those custom modules ?

Comment: yes, just set value 0 for rows, which you think that you have disabled accidentally.

Comment: @MohitKumarArora the modules i disabled are showing value `1` , so is i need to change those values to `0` ?

Comment: yes. Sorry, I have updated my previous comment.

Comment: @MohitKumarArora Thanks a lot for your support.  it was problem with some custom module, its really strange that disabling custom module is reason for this. please post answer.

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can access your website's database, then you can check which modules you have disabled by searching using like query with value path like %advanced/modules_disable_output/% in core_config_data table, and then enable if any module has been disabled accidentally.

Fire this query in database:

SELECT * FROM core_config_data WHERE path LIKE %advanced/modules_disable_output/%' ORDER BY path ASC;

It will give you rows of with all modules which are in enabled/disabled state.
Please let me know whether it could solve your problem.